# How to Cache Images Dynamically-Generated with PHP?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, caching, header

On a site, I am dynamically-generating images using PHP's ImageMagick extension.  I'm using the .htaccess file to rewrite files ending in .jpg to a php file for dynamic generation:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]+).jpg index.php?filename=$1
```

I am then creating images as JPG inside the PHP file:

```
$img->setImageFormat('jpeg');
```

Before echoing the image, I am sending out the following headers:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2027 05:00:00 GMT');
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=290304001");
```

However, using Chrome's "*Is it Cached?*" extension, I can see that the dynamically-generated images are **not** being cached.  Furthermore, Google Chrome's console is saying "*Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg*" despite having set the header as `Content-Type: image/jpeg`.

So I tried caching with .htaccess, using the following:

```
<filesMatch "\.(jpg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304001, public"
</filesMatch>
```

But that also did **not** work.

So I then tried adding the `php` extension to the .htaccess condition:

```
<filesMatch "\.(jpg|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304001, public"
</filesMatch>
```

And that **finally** worked and the images got cached.  So I'm relieved I got it to work, but this trial-and-error approach leaves me uneasy and I don't understand why the PHP cache headers didn't work.

Questions:

1) Is doing the caching via the .htaccess file the correct way to cache images dynamically-generated with PHP?

2) Why are the cache headers being sent out by PHP having **no effect**?

3) Why is Chrome's console saying "*Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg*" when the header has been set to `image/jpeg`?

4) Is there a better way of caching dynamically-generated images with PHP (perhaps using pure PHP without .htaccess)?