# How to cache dynamically created images?

Tags: php, caching, php-gd

I have a php script that generates *.png pictures but does **not** store them on the server. Those pictures will be shown to a same user repeatedly. I'm looking for a way to **cache** those pictures. I'm able to send the 304 status header, the browser also declares the webpage as cached at first refresh (as it is visible in the web-inspector) but the webpage is shown blank. After a second refresh even the web-inspector shows blank.

Can someone help me and tell where I messed up?

Notes:

- I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210451/how-to-cache-images-dynamically-generated-with-php) but it didn't help me.
- Using MAMP (PHP version 7.0.10)
- I'm a newbie, my apologies for the ugly code.

Here are the main lines of the file:

```
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
//A little require_once() here on some functions stored in an other file.
$originalSource = getSource($_GET['src']);
if (isset($_COOKIE[sha1($originalSource)]) && $_COOKIE[sha1($originalSource)]) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
    die;
} else {
    setcookie (sha1($originalSource), true, time()+10);
    $offset = 10;
    $expire = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
    header($expire);
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$offset);
    header("Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 12:00:00 GMT");
}
//The entire image generation process after this
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is the one deciding here whether it thinks the browser should still have the image cached or not. Obviously it is hardly the authority on that. There are any number of reasons why the browser may *not* have the image cached, e.g. if you open the inspector tools (which typically disables caching).

The browser has a mechanism for informing the server about its cache status: [the HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields) `If-None-Match` for [ETags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) and `If-Modified-Since` for time-based expiry. If any of these two headers is present in the request, that means the browser still has a copy of the resourced cached and would happily accept a `304` response instead of downloading the resource again.

If you set an `ETag` header in your response, the browser will do another request using `If-None-Match` (that essentially replaces your cookie mechanism, more reliably); if you just set an expiration date, the browser will check again with the server using the `If-Modified-Since` header. That's what you should base your `304` reply on.

Example using ETags:

```
$hash = sha1($originalSource);

header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT");

if (
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) &&
    trim($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'], '"') === $hash
) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
    exit;
}

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$offset");
header("ETag: \"$hash\"");

// output image
```

Comment: Thank you @deceze ! So my code now looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/7NwDTerH). But it still doesn't cache. [These](http://pastebin.com/W9812psa) are the headers I get.


 1. Do I need to enable "APC" or "OPCache" on MAMP?
 2. Do I need the `session_start();` ?
 3. Is it possible that `Pragma = no-cache` causes the issue?

Sorry for the big amount of questions.

Comment: APC etc. has nothing to do with this sort of cache. And yes, `Pragma              no-cache` seems counterproductive here.

Comment: Also note that your `Date` and `Expires` are identical, meaning it expires immediately.

Comment: Re your edit: the code with the variable in the string is correct as is.

Comment: Finally works even if I changed nothing.. time heals I suppose. Thanks for your help!